# Access Docker container running on local machine from Minikube cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, visibility, minikube

I've got an application in a local Kubernetes cluster(using Minikube). I also have an application started inside of a container running on my machine (outside of the cluster, in a docker container).

The Docker machine IP running on my machine is: 192.168.99.100

The Minikube IP is: 192.168.99.101

I want to make the application inside the container communicate with the one in the docker container outside of the cluster, but all requests fail with 404. It seems like the cluster doesn't have visibility to the docker container running my app.

Any suggestions how this can be remedied?

Comment: Have you created a service for your application in the Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: If I have to be more precise - the application running inside the cluster is the Service Catalog. The application running on my localhost inside a docker container is a Service Broker. All I'm trying to do is register the broker inside the Service Catalog but seems like the catalog can't reach the broker. (the Service Catalog is exposed through a service, but that's not the issue here I presume)

Comment: Do you access the Service Catalog through the Kubernetes Service?

Comment: No. I'm not interacting the the Service Catalog. The Service Catalog should be interacting with the Broker, that's how things go... But for some odd reason there's no visibility between the catalog and the broker.

Comment: To me it seems like the networking issue in th VM environment. Can you ping Docker Machine VM from inside the Minikube VM?